# Flutter OutlinedButton with icon ripple color

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use Outlined Button with icon, when if I set a color for the icon, it also changes the ripple effect color.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
    child: OutlinedButton.icon(
      label: Text(
        'Sign In With Google',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "RobotoCondensed",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 16),
      ),
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
        side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.google, color: Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {
        final provider =
            Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
        provider.login();
      },
    ),
  );
```

Can someone help me understand how can I define the ripple color to stay as black?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but try adding `foregroundColor` in `style`:

```
style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
  ...
  foregroundColor: Colors.black, //change colour here
),
```